# How do I properly average these percentages?

Tags: average, percentages

I have attendance records for an **annual** event:

> **person 1**: $4$ of $8$    attended $= 50.00$%, or every    $2$ years
>
> **person 2**: $1$ of $4$    attended $= 25.00$%, or every    $4$ years
>
> **person 3**: $4$ of $5$    attended $= 80.00$%, or every $1.25$ years

I want to show the percentage of events attended by the average person, so I aggregate the data, weighing each person equally:

> Avg attended $= 52$%
>
> Avg time interval = every $2.4 y$

The odd thing is this: $52$% attendance to an annual event **does not** correlate to attending every $2.4$ years. It correlates to every $1.9$ years.

So which is true of the above data? The average person comes $52$% of the time OR the average person comes every $2.4$ years? They can't both be true. Where have I gone wrong?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: There are a whole lot of apples to pears comparisons going on. I don't even see why an average here would be meaningful at all. For example, if one person attends 100 out of 100 exams, and another attends 0 out of 1 exams, Did the average person attend $50\%$ of the exams or did the average peson attend slightly below $100\%$ of the exams ($\frac{100}{101}$)?

Comment: Well, I want to know what percentage of events the average person attends. Or another way to say it, they attend every X years. So, I don't really even know the answer to your question.

Comment: Well if even you don't know that, how can *we* know what you want to ask?

Comment: I want to know what percentage of events the average person attends. How would you answer that question?

Comment: Yes, you said that twice, but that doesn't make it any clearer. What do you mean by "average person"? Do you mean "Pick a random person and look at the percentage of events"? In that case, you need to average the attendances from all people, so $52\%$ is the right answer.

Comment: So then I could say: "the average person comes to the event about every other year"? If so, why does the average of the per person time interval come out to 2.4? Do I just ignore that? (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35586/discussion-between-user3646932-and-5xum).

Comment: I don't understand why you think you should get the same number. The average of $2,3$ is $2.5$, and $\frac{1}{2.5}$ is not the same as the average of $\frac12,\frac13$. Why should it be?

Comment: Well, both the the average attendance and the average time interval seem meaningful and accurate for each individual. I see why it doesn't work. There is a non-linear relationship between the values. But I don't understand where the meaning is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In certain situations, especially many situations involving rates and ratios, the harmonic mean provides the truest average.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean

Comment: Working on it. Thanks.

Comment: So, If you wanted to explain the attendance of these 3 people, would you take the harmonic mean of the time interval or of the percentage attended? The harmonic mean of the percentage is 1/(arithmetic mean of the time interval) and vice versa. I end up with the same problem of not knowing which metric to use.

Comment: I found the geometric mean of both columns of values and the results DO correlate to one another. GeoAvg attendance = 46.4%, GeoAvg Interval = 2.15 years. That seems like a good thing, but I don't know what the Geometric Average really means, so I'm not sure to trust it. In your opinion, would those be valid numbers for the above data?

Comment: If you could standardize the number of events (same time span), this would clarify your data.  In other words, if all people were compared into attending the same 8 year period of person 1.  I'm not sure if this is possible.  If all 8 events were the same and available to all, you might pad with zeroes the missing events.  Otherwise, please explain how the data originated to help you better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The data relates to patient participation in screening exams that are recommended annually. We developed a method of determine, for each patient, a time span during which they should have been having annual exams, basically looking at first and last exam and determining how many in between they should have had. It's 20 years of data, so it varies from 1 to 20 possible exams. The plan was to extrapolate from whatever fragment of time we have an average compliance for that patient. Then aggregate that so each person would weigh equally, regardless of length.

Comment: I thought that converting the attendance fraction (3 of 8, 2 of 4, etc) into a percentage was equivalent to standardizing the number of events (same time span), but I certainly could be wrong about that.

Comment: For medical screenings, the data statistic is usually presented by segmenting the data into ethnicity, region, age and year of screen.  You have even more detail, because you keep track of the attendance of each person.  Averaging just the percentage of each person satisfies your equal weight of each, but 1 attendance out of 2 years is 50% and will weigh down a lot.  I would suggest averaging the total attendance over the total years.  So the average participation is: $\frac{4+1+4}{8+4+5}=52.94$%

Comment: Ironically, that is what we initially did, but decided that we were introducing a bias by weighting those patients with a longer history (the regulars) more heavily. At this point, I'm just happy to have a meaningful number, so we may just stick with that approach.

Comment: Ps- Any direct comments on the geometric mean? It seem like that is able to keep the varying scales of compliance and time interval proportional to one another. Would this be an inappropriate use of that average?

Comment: I'm glad you arrived to a meaningful number.  The geometric mean may help you out better if you were comparing for each person the two different properties, the attendance and the history in years, as to create an index of who is higher or lower in attendance-years.  Each property will be given the same weight relative to their own range.This is a "normalization".  So variations in attendance have the same weight as variation in history time span.  Unfortunately there is no meaningful 0%-100% range and both data are coupled or correlated (attendance somewhat follows the years time span).

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the answer is fairly simple. Lets take some intervals, as we did above:

> **person 1**: every   $1$ year
>
> **person 2**: every   $2$ years
>
> **person 3**: every $5$ years

Average those together and you get a value of :

> **average person**: every $2.67$ years

This is wrong. Imagine a 10 year interval and ask how many events each person attended:

> In $10$ years each person would attend:
>
> **person 1**: attends $10$ events
>
> **person 2**: attends $5$ events
>
> **person 3**: attends $2$ events

Average those together:

> **average person**: attends $5.67$ events in $10$ years OR $.567$ events per year OR every $1.76$ years, which is the correct answer

Arithmetic Average of the intervals is meaningless. So, how do you average $(1,2,5)$ together and arrive at an answer of $1.76$?

**Harmonic Mean**, just as CAGT mentions above. Thanks everyone for the help!